# getting object has no attribute 'get' or object is not subscriptable when trying to access JSON response converted to DTO

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to access a JSON response, I've trying with get() method and I'm getting the "object has no attribute 'get'" error and when I tried it with [] I'm getting the "object is not subscriptable" error.
The response is valid, as I've printed it just before the get operation and all looks ok.
Did not had such problem parsing a response before.

```
def get_return_params_and_identifiers(return_params):
    print("******** res start **********")
    print(return_params)
    print("******** res end **********")
    return_parameters = return_params.get('return_parameters')
```

Here is part of a response:

```
******** res start **********
{'levels': None,
 'return_parameters': [{'identifier_name': 'Premium',
                        'level': None,
                        'return_parameter_name_pk': 1258407,
                        'return_parameters_details': [{'base_parameter_name': 'Premium '
                                                                              'Parameter',
                                                       'base_parameter_pk': 1149913,
                                                       'class_value': None,
                                             ....
                                             ....
```

Did anybody encountered such and have any idea what is happening.

**EDIT:**

Tried with json.loads() but the response is a DTO and not JSON anymore and thus getting the other error:
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not DTO

The DTO class is below:

```
class ReturnParametersContainerDTO(object):
    """NOTE: This class is auto generated by the swagger code generator program.

    Do not edit the class manually.
    """
    """
    Attributes:
      swagger_types (dict): The key is attribute name
                            and the value is attribute type.
      attribute_map (dict): The key is attribute name
                            and the value is json key in definition.
    """
    swagger_types = {
        'return_parameters': 'list[ReturnParameterDTO]',
        'levels': 'LevelsDTO'
    }

    attribute_map = {
        'return_parameters': 'returnParameters',
        'levels': 'levels'
    }
```

It clearly says that the items in the class are dictionary, but somehow it does not recognize it.

Comment: What's the result of `print(type(return_params))`?

Comment: Type:  <class 'analytical_client.models.return_parameters_container_dto.ReturnParametersContainerDTO'>
 
I've updated the post with this DTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the issue.
It was something in the implementation of the OpenApi's generated DTO class, that showed it as a dictionary (in to_str() method it called to_dict() and prints it as a dictionary) but in fact those were just properties, so used the method to_dict() (in swagger's generated class) to convert it to dictionary.
Now all works.